# Check if package is installed, if not install it - Debian & RHEL in one script

Tags: bash, debian, yum, rhel, dpkg

I'd like to have bash script to check if a program is installed, and if not, to install it.
Could I run the same script on Debian and RHEL distributions?
The package will be installed from source with yum or dpkg.

1 script to be run on both distros

Comment: `for cmd in type hash command; do help "$cmd"; printf '\n=========\n\n'; done | less`

Comment: What you try so far?